# Create JavaScript object with an array with a multi select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am looking to create a JavaScript object to store values captured from some fields. I have dynamic fields where the user can add more fields to the page.

I am able to capture and store the fields in an object using the below code.

```
var attributes = document.getElementsByName("attribute[]");
var locations = document.getElementsByName("location[]");

var len = attributes.length;
var data = []
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
   var element = {
     "Attribute": attributes[i].value,
     "Location": locations[i].value,
   };
   data.push(element);
 };
```

Recently I had to add a `<select>` field called "Methods" to the dynamic fields, that allows users to select multiple methods in the drop down. I am struggling on how I can get the array of selected methods per "Attribute".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean that the `select` elements have the `multiple` attribute?

Comment: You do realise you can just push new objects (or arrays) into objects, right? We call it a 'multidimensional' object/array. Those things save programming lives. -- Or are you asking about how to GET the data you just SET? I'm sorry I'm a bit confused as to what you're asking, exactly.

Comment: Where's your HTML !!!

Comment: I hope you're not naming elements with `[]` in the name!

Comment: The `<select>` element will have child `<option>`s elements, you can loop over them and find the ones that are selected.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, there are server-sided languages that use this information to create arrays server-side.

Comment: @trincot I can't imaging any server-side language that doesn't allow you to inspect a name and create an array if the name follows a certain naming scheme. It doesn't mean you have to use `[]` in the HTML.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, sure, but some languages provide that conversion automatically based on the presence of these brackets. Using `[]` in attribute values is quite OK for HTML.

Comment: @trincot I know it's valid, but I don't recommend it as it becomes very confusing when used in client-side code where those `[]` in the name can easily be confused with real `[]` in JavaScript.

Comment: @trincot yes the `select` items have the `multiple` attribute applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a function as follow:**

```
function extract(select) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].selected) array.push(select.options[i].value);
  }

  return array
}
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var attributes = document.getElementsByName("attribute[]");
  var locations = document.getElementsByName("location[]");
  var methods = document.getElementsByName("methods[]");

  var len = attributes.length;
  var data = []
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    function extract(select) {
      var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
        if (select.options[i].selected) array.push(select.options[i].value);
      }

      return array;
    }

    var element = {
      "Attribute": attributes[i].value,
      "Location": locations[i].value,
      "Methods": extract(methods[i])
    };
    data.push(element);
  };
  
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<input name='attribute[]' placeholder='attribute[]' value=''>
<input name='location[]' placeholder='location[]' value=''>
<select multiple name='methods[]'>
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
<p/>
<input name='attribute[]' placeholder='attribute[]' value=''>
<input name='location[]' placeholder='location[]' value=''>
<select multiple name='methods[]'>
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
<p/>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `select` elements have a name attribute `options`:

```
var attributes = document.getElementsByName("attribute[]");
var locations = document.getElementsByName("location[]");
var options = document.getElementsByName("options[]"); //<--------

var len = attributes.length;
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
   var element = {
     "Attribute": attributes[i].value,
     // Grab the texts of the selected options:
     options: Array.from(options[i].querySelectorAll('option:checked'), 
                         option => option.textContent),
     "Location": locations[i].value,
   };
   data.push(element);
}
```

Note that you can use the `Array.from` callback argument (and short arrow function syntax) to create the `data` array:

```
var attributes = document.getElementsByName("attribute[]");
var locations = document.getElementsByName("location[]");
var options = document.getElementsByName("options[]");
var data = Array.from(attributes, (attrib, i) => ({
    Attribute: attrib.value,
    options: Array.from(options[i].querySelectorAll('option:checked'), 
                        option => option.textContent),
    Location: locations[i].value,
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried this solution as well and it worked. Can see where I needed to make some changes.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) I see you went with the other answer & solution.